# Flutter application release is different than debug

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deployment, release

I have created an app in flutter using Android studio which I want to deploy.

Flutter version is 2.10.

Dart version is  2.16.0.

When I run or debug main.dart from Android studio everything works as expected.
I have signed the application following the instructions from here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

I have created the keystore using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -genkey -v -keystore c:\upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Created key.properties file with the following content

```
storePassword=password from previous step
keyPassword=password from previous step
keyAlias=key
storeFile=location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/upload-keystore.jks
```

in [project]/android/app/build.gradle added the keystore information before the Android block as follow

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

and replaced

```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
```

with

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

And after changing the gradle file I ran flutter clean.
After the specified steps the application can still the debugged and can be ran as expected.
I am building a bundle with the following command

```
flutter build appbundle
```

The build is successful and I get the output file in

```
build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab
```

Using bundletool I convert the .aab file to apks and install it on my phone with the following commands:

```
java -jar "PATH/bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar" build-apks --bundle=PATH/app-release.aab --ks="PATH/upload-keystore.jks" --ks-key-alias=key --output=PATH/app-release.apks
java -jar "PATH/bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar" install-apks --apks=PATH/app-release.apks
```

where PATH is the path to the directory of the file.
After the app is being installed and launched I get the attached window

[image]

which is completely different than the app I wrote.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
Stanko

Comment: I see no reason why app from APK should be different than made by flutter. Are you sure you are in right folder? Have you tried launch it by `flutter run` command?

Comment: You're right Tomas, flutter run is indeed running the program from the screenshot. But when I run the programing using ALT+SHIFT+F9 (Debug) or ALT+SHIFT+F10 (Release) in Android Studio a different app is starting. Is there a way to check the run path or specify another build path ? Thank you for your time! Stanko

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tomas's comment I have found the solution.
Running the following command

```
flutter run
```

a different project has been started, so I had to use this instead

```
flutter run PATH/lib/src/main.dart
```

which started the correct project, similarly for the app bundle I had to run

```
flutter build appbundle PATH/lib/src/main.dart
```

Thank you for your help!

Best wishes,
Stanko

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad my little comment helped. :)